# How can I append text from a input to single items via a JSON GET request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have created and Instagram clone and I am having some trouble with appending comments to individual `<div>` elements. What I would like to accomplish is to have a user type some text in the `<input>` box, click the submit button, and have said text appear under the `<input>` area via a `<li>` in a `<ul>` I created called `comment-list`. Similarly, I would only like said input to be targeted to each specific image imported from my JSON GET request without text duplication on any single item. The jQuery seems right to be able to append the text, but it isn't working and a fresh pair of eyes certainly wouldn't hurt.

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tecaha/edit?output

Code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="top">



        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li id="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SmdPZ6T.png" />
          </li>
          <li id="profile-photo">
            <img src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10731946_1517235648523785_1216221661_a.jpg" />
            <p class="username">username</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
      <main>
        <div id="feed-container">
            <ul id="images">





            </ul>
          </div>




      </main>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3E6D93;
  height: 50px;
}
.top {
  background: #467ea6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.01, #467ea6), to(#27608c));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#467ea6', endColorstr='#27608c', GradientType=0);
  width: 100%;
}
.top li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#home-button, .fa-home {
  float: left;
  background-color: #305F87;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 35px;
}
.fa-home {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
#logo img {
  float: right;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 6px;
}
#profile-photo  {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #305F87;
  border-right: 1px solid #305F87;
  width: auto;
}
#profile-photo img  {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#profile-photo p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;

}
#feed-container {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#images img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}
.below-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like {
  float: left;
}
.fa-heart {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.liked {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.image-info {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 437px;
  height: 52px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image-info p {
  color: #467ea6;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.more {
  float: right;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
.more, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
#clear {
  clear: both;
}
.comment-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

#add-a-comment {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#add-a-comment p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#add-a-comment input[type=text] {
  width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #f00;
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
#comment-click {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;

  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.inserted {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post-liked .fa-heart {
   color: #f00;
}
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
    // Variable of html strings
var bottom = '<div class="below-image">' +
    '<div class="like">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="image-info">' +
    '<p>User Info</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="more">' +
    '<button class="info">···</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id="clear"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div id="add-a-comment">' +
    '<div class="comment-container">' +
    '<form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">' +
    '<input id="enter" type="text" name="newcomment" value="" placeholder="Add a comment...">' +
    '<button id="comment-click">Submit</button>' +
    '</form>' +
    '<ul class="comment-list">' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
   '</div>';


// GET Request to grab the data from the JSON file
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonURL = "https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json";
  var newImage = "http://yourbizrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Staying-Motivated.jpg";

  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
      var imgList = "";

    $.each(json, function (i) {
        imgList += '<div class="post"><li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + json[i] + ' ">' + bottom;

        });

        $('#images').append(imgList);

    });
});

// Like Photos
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#images').on('click', '.inserted', function() {
//  $('.fa-heart').toggleClass('liked');
      var post_block = $(this).parents('.post').first();
       post_block.toggleClass('post-liked');
    });
});

// $('img.inserted').on('dblclick', function(){
//   var post_block = $(this).parents('.post').first();
//   post_block.addClass('post-liked');
//   console.log('Test');
// });


// Add Comment
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#comment-click').on('click', function() {
       var userComment = $('input[name=newcomment]').val();
       $(".comment-list").append("<li>" + userComment + "</li>");

    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to use classes, not id's, if you are going to have the same html repeated over and over again.

Then, your jQuery to add click event handlers was running before the json returned. It saw nothing to add event handlers to, and affected nothing. I moved the code into the callback function of the `getJSON`.

Finally, if you want to reference a specific field, you will need to use `this` just like you did with "Liking" photos.

```js
// Variable of html strings
var bottom = '<div class="below-image">' +
    '<div class="like">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="image-info">' +
    '<p>User Info</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="more">' +
    '<button class="info">···</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="clear"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="add-a-comment">' +
    '<div class="comment-container">' +
    '<form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">' +
    '<input id="enter" type="text" name="newcomment" value="" placeholder="Add a comment...">' +
    '<button class="comment-click">Submit</button>' +
    '</form>' +
    '<ul class="comment-list">' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
 '</li>' +
   '</div>';


// GET Request to grab the data from the JSON file
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonURL = "https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json";
  var newImage = "http://yourbizrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Staying-Motivated.jpg";
    
  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
    var imgList = "";
        
    $.each(json, function (i) {
        imgList += '<div class="post"><li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + json[i] + ' ">' + bottom;
      
    });
    
    
    $('#images').append(imgList);
    
    
// Like Photos
    $('#images').on('click', '.inserted', function() {
//  $('.fa-heart').toggleClass('liked');
      var post_block = $(this).parents('.post').first();
      post_block.toggleClass('post-liked');
    });
  
// Add Comment
    $('.comment-click').on('click', function() {
      var userComment = $(this).siblings('input[name=newcomment]').val();
      $(this).parent().siblings('.comment-list').append("<li>" + userComment + "</li>");
    
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3E6D93;
  height: 50px;
}
.top {
  background: #467ea6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.01, #467ea6), to(#27608c));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#467ea6', endColorstr='#27608c', GradientType=0);
  width: 100%;
}
.top li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#home-button, .fa-home {
  float: left;
  background-color: #305F87;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 35px;
}
.fa-home {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
#logo img {
  float: right;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 6px;
}
#profile-photo  {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #305F87;
  border-right: 1px solid #305F87;
  width: auto;
}
#profile-photo img  {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#profile-photo p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;

}
#feed-container {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#images img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}
.below-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like {
  float: left;
}
.fa-heart {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.liked {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.image-info {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 437px;
  height: 52px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image-info p {
  color: #467ea6;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.more {
  float: right;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
.more, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.comment-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.add-a-comment {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.add-a-comment p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.add-a-comment input[type=text] {
  width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #f00;
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
.comment-click {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.inserted {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post-liked .fa-heart {
   color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="top">

        
        
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li id="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SmdPZ6T.png" />
          </li>
          <li id="profile-photo">
            <img src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10731946_1517235648523785_1216221661_a.jpg" />
            <p class="username">username</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
      <main>
        <div id="feed-container">
            <ul id="images">
              
              
              
              
              
            </ul>
          </div>

          

          
      </main>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help. I see that you have added jQuery 2.1 above the `<DOCTYPE html>` can you explain that to me please?

Comment: That was just related to trying to put it in the code snippet editor for stackoverflow. It wasn't necessary (and didn't belong there), and I have removed it.

Comment: I assumed that was the case. Thanks again!